# How does composer manage dynamic inclusion of libraries into script?

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer being dependency manager tool installs packages from packagist according to their specifications in **composer.json file**. Those libraries are referred into script through inclusion of **vendor/autoload.php** file into script.How does it manage dynamic inclusion of libraries into script?

Answer (score 0):

define your autoload function, it's in php http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php